# How to use same inner class in different List classes?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am working on a problem where I implement different Linked lists. All the list classes include two inner classes; a Node-class and an Iterator-class.

These inner classes are entirely identical to each other. In the Iterator-class, some of the methods rely on accessing information from the outer class, which works fine. Is there a way to do this in java, so that I would not need to include the very same code in all my different list-classes? I feel clueless - I just don't know where to look.

This is what my Node-class looks like:

```
class Node{
    Node next;
    Node previous;
    private T data;

    Node(T inn){
        data = inn;
    }

    public Node getNesteNode(){
        return next;
    }
    public T getData(){
        return data; 
    }
}
```

Edit: I realize the Node class is relying entirely on itself.

Here is my simple Iterator:

```
class LenkeListeIterator implements Iterator<T>{
    private int field = 0;   
    Node denne = forste;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {

        return field!= storrelse();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {

        T data = denne.getData();
        denne = denne.getNesteNode();
        field++;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make them not inner classes.

Comment: "so that I would not need to include the very same code in all my different list-classes" Sure, make it a top-level class, or otherwise accessible outside those classes. Assuming you mean `next` rather than `neste`, you don't use the enclosing reference here, so you can make the class static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) is an intrinsic part of the class containing it. It can only be shared with subclasses, not peers or classes outside the hierarchy of the parent class entirely.

There's nothing in your `Node` class that requires it to be an inner class, so you could just make it standalone. But if there *were* something that made it need to be an inner class, you could put all the parts that *don't* into a standalone class that is then subclassed in each of the parent classes to provide it with access to the parent's inner data.

E.g. *(roughly)*:

```
abstract class Example {
    protected int something;

    public void logic() {
        SomeType data = this.getParentData();
        /* ...do something with `data`... */
    }

    abstract protected SomeType getParentData();
}
```

Then an inner class in, say, `Container` would subclass it and provide `getParentData`.

```
class Container {
    private SomeType data;

    class ContainerExample extends Example {
        protected SomeType getParentData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have no clue how I did not realize the Node-class could be a standalone class. Seemingly not much to gain from making a super iterator class though, as most methods and fields rely on access to the outer class.

Comment: @user2005142: Yeah, probably not. Better off with a superclass for the container with the iterator class (like `AbstractList`'s private `ListIterator`).